# VSCode doesn't display colors correctly in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

How it should be

[image: screenshot showing colored text in terminal]

How it is

[image: screenshot showing sections that should be colored wrapped in sequences of "←[{numbers}m"]

As you can see, one device doesn't support those colors. VSCode version is 1.70.2 on both devices. The one that doesn't work is Windows 7. I guess that might have something to do with it.

Comment: What you're seeing are ANSI escape sequences. I don't use Windows 7, but this looks useful: [VSCode: ANSI Colors in Terminal](/q/49928836/4518341). You might also check out [How to recognize ansi color escape codes in Windows7 64 bit command terminal](/q/2294281/4518341) and [How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences in `c`?](/q/16755142/4518341)

Comment: Installing ANSICON and running it fixed it. After installing it, you need to change default terminal to cmd from powershell in vscode settings for anyone running into the same issue.